# Creating a copy/clone of imageview android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I am creating a drag and drop application that drags an object on the main layout. My problem is I want to have unlimited/infinity copy of the image view so I can drag the image as many as I can.

For example the heart shape, when I already drag the image I cannot have another heart shape because I only have one image(heart) in the layout.

[image]

This is my code on touch on imageViews (Star, Heart, lightning):

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
          DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);
          view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
          view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
      }

    }
```

this is my drag listener of the drop zone/main image:

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    @Override
      public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        final int X = (int) event.getX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // do nothing
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
          View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
          ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          owner.removeView(view);
          RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;

          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
           params1.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - 15;
           params1.topMargin = (int) event.getY() -15;

          container.addView(view,params1);
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
          default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop in your case is much easier to develop with canvas.

Create a class that extends View, make a rect to draw you image inside, setOntouch on that view, let rect follow your touch, and use invalidate() to force redraw the view.

**Edit**
When using canvas you don't get headache from margins and layout parameters, it's just straightforward.

DragDropView.java

```
public class DragDropView extends View implements OnTouchListener  {
    Rect originalRect , draggableRect;
    int left, right, top, bottom, newX, newY, size;
    Drawable originalDrawable,draggableDrawable;

    public DragDropView(Context context)
    {
        super(context, null);
        size = 20;
        originalRect= new Rect();
        originalRect.set(200, 200, 240, 240); //left , top , right , bottom
        draggableRect= new Rect();
        draggableRect.set(200, 200, 240, 240);
        originalDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        draggableDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        originalDrawable.setBounds(originalRect); // since it wont move no need to do that in onDraw()
        newX = 220;
        newY=220;
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    public DragDropView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {    super(context, attrs);    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        originalDrawable.draw(canvas);
        draggableRect.set(newX-size, newY-size, newX+size, newY+size);
        draggableDrawable.setBounds(draggableRect);
        draggableDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        newX = (int)event.getX();
        newY = (int)event.getY();
        invalidate(); // force redraw

        //if you need special touch events
//      //on touch down
//      if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
//      {   }
//      //on touch move
//      if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
//      {   }
//      //on touch up
//      if( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
//      {   }

        return true; // always return true to let touch listener listen to next touch
    }
}
```

YourActivity.java

```
DragDropView dragDropView = new DragDropView();
```

Comment: Yes at the office google it its very easy, best part is that you can "clone" hundreds of that image by calling a single draw line

Comment: How can I use your code and partially what I have to achieve my request here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213027/how-to-allow-user-to-drag-and-drop-an-image-within-a-linearlayout

Comment: Create the same view above your image, and remove originalDrawable from class, load your hollow box image into draggableDrawable, on tuoch you can move it and get absolute/relative xy and convert them into your hex or rbg