# How to get the xy position of the 4 corners of my image view android

Tags: android, image-resizing

I am creating a resize feature for my photo editor on android. I want to put a circle/dot on the corners of the imageView everytime I touch the image. So that I can drag that circles to resize the image.

My problem is how to get the xy position of the 4 corners of the imageview. For now I am creating for the upper left corner:

```
  ImageView edgePoints = null;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    findViewById(R.id.imageBlue).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imgstage).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener()); 
    edgePoints = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.edgePoint); // the dot/circle
    edgePoints.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}   


Private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
          ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
          DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view);
          view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


          ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          if(owner.getId() == R.id.imgstage)
          {
              lastImageSelected = (ImageView) view;
              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              params1.leftMargin = view.getLeft();
              params1.topMargin = view.getTop();
              edgePoints.setLayoutParams(params1);
               edgePoints.setVisibility(View.Visible);
          }

          return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
      }

    }
```

This is my drag listener

```
     class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    @Override
      public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        final int X = (int) event.getX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:        
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
          View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
          ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
          ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageView.getWidth()/9, imageView.getWidth()/9);
          params1.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - ((imageView.getWidth()/9)/2);
          params1.topMargin = (int) event.getY() -((imageView.getWidth()/9)/2);


          if(owner.getId() != R.id.imgstage)
          {
              owner.removeView(view);
              RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
              container.addView(view,params1);
          }
          else
              view.setLayoutParams(params1);

          view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


          if(owner.getId() != R.id.imgstage)
          {
              FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) owner;
              Context context = getApplicationContext();


              ImageView imv=new ImageView(context);
              FrameLayout.LayoutParams marginParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              marginParams.setMargins(4, 4, 4, 4);
              imv.setLayoutParams(marginParams);


              imv.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

              if(owner.getId() == R.id.blueLayout)   
                  imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.blueblock);
              if(owner.getId() == R.id.orageLayout) 
                  imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.orangeblock);
              if(owner.getId() == R.id.redLayout) 
                  imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.redblock);
              if(owner.getId() == R.id.greenLayout) 
                  imv.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenblock);

              layout.addView(imv);//to be included
          }
          break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
          default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }
  }
```

Comment: There are getRight() and getBottom() methods as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your app crashes is because you try to add `edgePoints` to the layout more than once. You cannot add a view, if it is already added.

Solution is to add the view before calling, `onTouch` and keep it `INVISIBLE`. Then,  onTouch, you should do something like:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params1.leftMargin = lastImageSelected.getLeft();
        params1.topMargin = lastImageSelected.getTop();

        edgePoints.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        edgePoints.setLayoutParams(params1);
    }
}
```

Just set the `layout params` don't call `addView()`

Comment: But if I want to implement on 4 corners, I must create 4 ImageView?

Comment: Actually, I gave a solution to why your app crashes. (Since you said, for first touch everything works). For the four corners thing.. please post more code. What is `edgePoints`, how do you init it.. etc..?

Comment: I edited my question. My problem now I need to touch twice my ImageView before my edge points move.

Comment: Does it show on the left corner? Does it work right nowe without crashing?

Comment: Yes! but it gets the last left corner after I touch the image. I need to move the image twice, but as I said it gets the last position of the left corner.

Comment: Ok firstly, i do not understand what you mean by _"touch twice.. move the image twice_". What is the _"last left corner"_ Secondly, i don't know how you move the image, so please post that code too..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40544/discussion-between-mmakati-and-amulya-khare)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a photo editor its better to do it on your own view, about re-sizing there its easy you just draw a rect which contains the image and four small rects on the edges, the advantage of using your own view is that it's much easier to get coordinates and manipulate them, and you won't get  the layout parameters headache.

have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660874/creating-a-copy-clone-of-imageview-android/19661207#19661207)

Comment: Is it possible to drag the small rectangles to resize the image. I dont have any idea on how to do this.

Comment: yes, by moving any rectangle edge the rect will be resized and the image inside will be automatically resized

Comment: Can I simply put a rectangle on the imageview so that I can resize the rectangle? Is that possible?